# Creating multiple Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I am a novice developer, so please excuse my question.

I have made an app, and I now require several types of notifications, mostly differences in the content text.  I have tried using 2 different Receivers, which I believe is not allowed.  In any case, it didn't work.

I tried using a global variable ("public static int NOTIFICATION;") to change the text in the notification, and although it works perfectly while the app is running, if I close the app, the NOTIFICATION ends up being 0 every time.

I have been searching high and low all day for a solution but cannot find one.  Can this be done?  I assume so, since I see notifications from apps that use different text in their content.

Thank you

Comment: You could try setting up the the variable as ```volatile```
Inside the main Activity
Not sure if the variable would persist.
The other option is to save the value of the variable in onStop/onDestroy methods of the Activity and then load them when relaunching the application

Comment: Can you clarify your question with some reference code and screenshots if possible?

Comment: I forgot to add the second receiver to the manifest. Once I did that, it worked just fine.